# Hashcode decryption

Tags: java, lambda

where i did mistake here?

> Optional.empty Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: NULL     at
>   flagctf.IsItTheFlag.lambda$2(IsItTheFlag.java:28)     at
>   java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)     at
>   flagctf.IsItTheFlag.main(IsItTheFlag.java:28)

```
    public class IsItTheFlag {

    private static boolean isFlag(String str) {
        return str.hashCode() == 1471587914 && str.toLowerCase().hashCode() == 1472541258;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String TheFlag = "------";

        Stream<String> aStream = Stream.empty();
        for (int i = 0; i < TheFlag.length(); i++) {
            aStream = aStream.flatMap(IsItTheFlag::word);
        }
        Optional<String> stringStream = aStream
                .parallel()
                .filter(IsItTheFlag::isFlag)
                .findAny();

        System.out.println(stringStream);

        String flag = stringStream.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("NULL"));


        if (isFlag(flag))
            System.out.println("You found it!");
        else
            System.out.println("Try again :(");
    }

    private static Stream<Character> letters() {
        Stream<Character> from_a_to_z = IntStream.range((int) 'a', 1 + (int) 'z').mapToObj(x -> (char) x);
        Stream<Character> from_A_to_Z = IntStream.range((int) 'A', 1 + (int) 'Z').mapToObj(x -> (char) x);
        Stream<Character> from_0_to_9 = IntStream.range((int) 'A', 1 + (int) 'Z').mapToObj(x -> (char) x);
        return Stream.concat(
                Stream.concat(from_a_to_z, from_A_to_Z),
                from_0_to_9);
    }

    private static Stream<String> word(String prefix) {
        return letters().map(x -> prefix + x);
    }

}
```

Comment: _mistake_? Why? What would you expect the code does?

Comment: How many elements do you expect in an empty stream?

Answer (score 1):

You invoke this processing pipeline on an empty stream `aStream` which leads to an empty Optional.

```
aStream.parallel().filter(IsItTheFlag::isFlag).findAny();
```

Since the value inside the `Optional` is empty, you throw this exception.

```
stringStream.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("NULL"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
str.hashCode() == 1471587914 && str.toLowerCase().hashCode() == 1472541258;
```

is fishy. Strings are sort-of value types in Java, so if you have two strings that are both "meow", chances are good that they occupy the same memory space, and therefore have the same `hashcode()`. However, if you take the `toLowerCase()` of that string, you get a new, different string, and a very high probability of a different hash code.

So the question is, what exactly are you trying to achieve with that line?